# Contagem de Numeros pares (linguagem c)

Tags: c, contador

Preciso exibir na tela os números entre um valor incial e final digitados, após isso escrever quantos são pares.
ex. 2 e 10
vai exibir na tela: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8 ,9, 10.

depois dizer a qtd de pares tem aí (seriam 5, no caso).
Não consigo executar essa ultima parte.

```
for (val1; val1 <= val2; val1++)
    {
          printf("\n%d ", val1);
    }
    if (val1%2==0)
    {
    par++;
    }
    printf ("\n Entre os valores %d e %d, existem %d números pares.", val1, val2, par);
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você não está comparando se o `val1` é par ou não dentro do loop `for`, você está "fechando" o loop antes disso:

```c
for (val1; val1 <= val2; val1++)
    {
          printf("\n%d ", val1);
>>> }
    if (val1%2==0)
...
```

Basta retirar a `}` que está logo após este `printf` e adicioná-la no final (após a chave final do `if`):

```c
...
for (val1; val1 <= val2; val1++)
    {   
    printf("\n%d ", val1);

    if (val1 % 2 == 0)
    {   
            par++;
    }   
}
printf ("\n Entre os valores %d e %d, existem %d números pares.", val1-val2, val2, par);
...
```

Desta forma o código irá funcionar conforme desejado.

Answer (score 1):

Como *parece* um exercício, pode ser que seja "obrigatório" iterar um por um e usar o operador `%` (e aí a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/513816/112052) já disse como fazer).

Mas dá para fazer um pouquinho melhor. Basta garantir que você está começando por um número par, e aí basta iterar de 2 em 2:

```
// ... ler val1 e val2

int n = val1;
// se o valor inicial é ímpar, soma 1 para que ele seja par
if (n % 2 != 0)
    n++;

// agora eu sei que n é par, então posso fazer o for de 2 em 2
int cont = 0;
for(; n <= val2; n += 2) {
    printf("%d\n", n);
    cont++;
}
printf("Entre os valores %d e %d existem %d números pares.\n", val1, val2, cont);
```

Ou seja, se `val1` for ímpar, eu somo 1 para que o `for` comece em um número par. E como agora eu garanti que sempre começa em um número par, posso fazer o `for` de 2 em 2 (ou seja, `n += 2`). Assim eu só uso o operador `%` uma vez, antes do *loop* (em vez de iterar por todos os números, um a um, e usar `%` para todos).

E veja que na primeira expressão dentro do `for` você não precisa colocar `val1` "solto" ali, pode deixar vazio mesmo (se não vai fazer nada, não coloque nada).

Como você quer imprimir `val1` no final, então não pode mudá-lo no *loop*, por isso usei outra variável para isso (no caso, o `n`).

---

Se bem que, se fosse só para saber a quantidade, nem precisa ficar contando. Afinal, entre `a` e `b` (desde que `a` seja par), a quantidade de números pares é `((b - a) / 2) + 1`. O *loop* só é necessário para imprimir os números. Ou seja:

```
int n = val1;
// se o valor inicial é ímpar, soma 1 para que ele seja par
if (n % 2 != 0)
    n++;

// não precisa contar dentro do loop
int cont = ((val2 - n) / 2) + 1;

// agora eu sei que n é par, então posso fazer o for de 2 em 2
for(; n <= val2; n += 2) {
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
printf("Entre os valores %d e %d existem %d números pares.\n", val1, val2, cont);
```